# Combine multiple regex (match and replace) into one regex; optimize for speed

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a PHP preg_match function implementation where I am comparing a known RegEx with a cleaned version of another variable. I am cleaning using multiple preg_replace etc commands. I was wondering if there is an alternate way to do the same logic which is smaller (maybe involving only one reg match) and quicker (matching several times is more complex then doing just once).

Here is my current code:

```
$url_regex_to_match = /SOME_REGEX/; //I will pick this from DB

$matches = array();

//Following to replace http://www.google.com into http://google.com
preg_match('/(http.?):\/\/(www\.)?(.*)/i', $url, $matches);
if(sizeof($matches)==4) {
    $url = $matches[1]."://".$matches[3]; 
}
//Incase the preg_match is false (http is missing), we still need to remove www.
$url = preg_replace("/(^\*?|\/\/)www\./i","$1",$url);

//It converts google.com/a#mno into google.com/a
$url = preg_replace('/^(.*)(#.*)$/', '$1', $url);
//It converts pages like google.com/index.htm into google.com/
$url = preg_replace('/^(.*\/)((home|default|index)\..{3,4})(\?.*)*$/', '$1$4', $url);
//This will replace google.com/ into google.com
if(substr($url, -1) == "/") {
    $url = substr($url, 0, -1);
}

//This is just to match the new URLs with the pattern I have
$boolean = preg_match($url_regex_to_match , $url);
```

The expected value of Boolean is ofcourse true / false.

Thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps add some comments that explain what the intended result is?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added some comments. Let me know in case you want it to be more clear

Comment: So really, you want to extract the domain name part of the URL? You should probably use an URL parsing library for that instead of trying to roll your own regular expression-based solution; there are lots of corner cases for URLs that can trip you up.  See PHP's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: Not really. But right now my question was to combine regex in general. This is one example where I need to use it, but there are other examples in my code I want to improve

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what exactly do you want. I mean extracting the domain can be done in a single new regex like this:

```
preg_replace/http[s]*:\/\/[\w\d\.-]*\.([\d\w-]*)\..+\/(.*)/i,"$1")
```

So basically my answer is: build *one* regex for your problem instead of many. I don't see any way what to do else as the other way would basically require the computer to understand what the regex searches for and put that together (which would most likely result in slower regex). If my solution does not help you, please let me know in a comment.

Edit: Sorry, I clarified my regex.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. It doesnt fit my logic as per original question and moreover is not giving expected answers in case of sub domains.

Comment: I calarified my regex. I thought regex would output the same, no matter if php or not and the new one even outputs the correct domain for `"http://mail35.5-5mail.go23o4-gl1e.com/calendar/index.htm"`